# сложный TextView - обтекание текстом картинки

Tags: java, android, textview, android-layout, customview

Есть приложение которое может отображать в одной активити фото и какой-то текст. Например, так как это схематически представлено на прикрепленном рисунке.[image: пример отображения]

Возможно ли реализовать это таким образом на Android?

Полагаю что с картинкой сбоку и снизу должны граничить два `TextView` (при отображение текста) или `EditText` (при вводе теста),  которые работают как одно. То есть, вводится (отображается) текст в "боковом" виджете, а когда в нем количество строк превышает какое-то определенное число, второй ("нижний") виджет получает фокус и пользователь продолжает, как ни в чем не бывало, вводить текст.

То же самое происходит при отображении этого теста только используется TextView.Размеры картинки фиксированные, но она может и отсутствовать в активити (в таком случае проблем не будет).

Или есть какой-то другой удобный способ отображения текста и картинки, так чтоб это выглядело аккуратно и не было лишнего простого пространства на экране?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494158/how-to-align-textview-around-an-imageview

Comment: Можешь библиотеку [*TextWrapView*](https://github.com/venator85/TextWrapView) глянуть, как там все устроено или даже не напрягаться самому, а использовать ее в своем проекте (как обычно делают разумные люди, когда им требуется уже реализованная функциональность)